# Magento 2 REST Api POST Picture / Media

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, media-images

I am trying to POST to

```
192.168.2.153/rest/V1/products/{MYSKU}/media
```

I used several online picture to BASE64 converter to convert to BASE64.

The first line looks like

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA
```

And here is my body (without the BASE64 code to save space here):

```
{
"entry": {
"media_type": "image",
"label": "new_picture",
"types": [
  "image"
],
"file": "pic1.jpg",
"content": {
  "base64_encoded_data": "",
  "type": "image",
  "name": "pic1.jpg"
}
  }
}
```

I am only getting

```
The image content must be valid base64 encoded data.
```

Whatever I try no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base64_encoded_data should start with **/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA**, no need to add **data:image/jpeg;base64,** before
the type also should be   **image/jpeg**

the final json should be

```
{
  "entry": {
    "media_type": "image",
    "label": "new_picture",
    "types": [
      "image"
    ],
    "file": "pic1.jpg",
    "content": {
      "base64_encoded_data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA.........",
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "name": "pic1.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to upload image in media but image is not uploaded but in media blank path is generated "media/tmp/catalog/product/c/h" Please help me how can upload image.